# Start pulseaudio in root after install tmux(centos7.3)?

Tags: centos, tmux, pulseaudio

when I start tmux, error like this:
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: failed to start backgroud process.

I search for this problem, but can't find proper solution, Does anyone have this problem ever?

Answer (score 1):

Pulseaudio is not intended to run in root environment, but it you can run by specifying --system.